# DataFrame with string column-names

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem:
I constructed a DataFrame with integer column-names and a period-index. Now, if I rename the columns using the following function:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: str(x), inplace=True)
```

Hence, I convert the type of the columns to string I observe the following weird behavior:
Before the operation if I retreive one column from the frame I got a Series. Now, on some columns I obtain a DataFrame:
formerly `df.loc[:,1]` gave a Series:

Now, `df.loc[:,'1']` gives a DataFrame with a PeriodIndex of length 0 and the full original columns of df.

Does anybody have an idea whether I am doing something wrong or did I stumble upon a bug?

Here is a code-snippet which reproduces the bug(?):

```
A = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(range(0,9000), [pd.Series([1,2,3], [pd.Period(1), pd.Period(2), pd.Period(3)]) for x in range(0,9000)])))

A[5000]
A.rename(columns = lambda x: str(x), inplace=True)

A['5000'] # This should return a DataFrame with a zero-PeriodIndex and the full columns!
```

Thank you very much in advance and best regards
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is in master. looks correct

```
In [11]: A = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(range(0,9000), [pd.Series([1,2,3], [pd.Period(1), pd.Period(2), pd.Period(3)]) for x in range(0,9000)])))

In [12]: A['5000']
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
PeriodIndex: 0 entries
Columns: 9000 entries, 0 to 8999
dtypes: int64(9000)

In [13]: A[5000]
Out[13]: 
1-01-01    1
1-01-02    2
1-01-03    3
Freq: D, Name: 5000, dtype: int64

In [14]: A.rename(columns = lambda x: str(x), inplace=True)

In [15]: A['5000']
Out[15]: 
1-01-01    1
1-01-02    2
1-01-03    3
Freq: D, Name: 5000, dtype: int64

In [16]: A[5000]
KeyError: u'no item named 5000'
```

Comment: That is strange. I am using python 2.7.3 and pandas 0.11.0. Which version are you using?

I investigated the problem further: the strange behavior starts as of index 32/'32'...

To be more precise regarding "gives a DataFrame with a PeriodIndex of length 0 and the full original columns of df.":


A['5000']
Out[5]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
PeriodIndex: 0 entries
Columns: 9000 entries, 0 to 8999
dtypes: int64(9000)

Comment: this is on master (0.12)...coming this week....0.11 is different; I seem to remember some fixing of this (relating to the order of what its checking)...

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you very much, looking forward to the new release!

Comment: Can you think of any quick workaround which spares me the hassle to stick with numerical column-names?

Comment: ``A.iloc[:,5000]``, will find explicity based on the column number (regardless of the label); ``A.loc[:,'5000']`` explicity uses the label, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#choice, works in 0.11

Comment: hmmm..must be another bug that was fixed; temp workaround is to use ``A.iloc[:,32]`` until 0.12, where ``A.loc[:,'32']`` works, and ``A['32']`` for that matter

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your quick response, that clarified a lot!